# Relocate directory within repository

Tags: svn

I'm still getting my head around the finer points of Subversion.

I have a repository structure like so:

```
/trunk
/tags
/branches
```

and one local working copy that is a checkout of `/trunk`

I would like to move those directories *within the repository* to

```
/website/trunk
/website/tags
/website/branches
```

To make way for a number of other projects that need to be in that repository as well.

What is the most clever way to do this, in terms of the log history staying intact?

What would I do to re-connect my local working copy with the new directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Commit all changes before doing this
2. Do a checkout of the repository's root (the path containing trunk, tags, branches)
3. Create the folder "website" and "svn add" it (precondition for svn move)
4. SVN move the other three folders into it
5. Commit
6. SVN update all working copies you have

Answer (score 2):

`svn move` the directories, and then `svn switch` your working copy to the new "trunk".